# Shell/Bash - pipe output into another script's input via a variable

Tags: bash, pipe

Normally I would break things into separate actions and copy and paste the output into another input:

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
$ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/local/bin/git
```

Any quick hack to get output into input?
something like:
`$echo which wget | sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain`

Comment: The example output from `which git` does not appear in the next command. It sounds like you want command substitution, but your example is unclear.

Comment: That still looks like you want to overwrite one binary with another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set -vx
myGit=$(which git)
gitDir=${myGit#/git} ; gitDir=${gitDir#/bin}/git
echo sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain ${gitDir}
```

Remove the `set -vx` and the `echo` on the last line when you're sure this performs the action that you require.

It's probably possible to reduce the number of keystrokes required, but I think this version is easier to understand what techniques are being used, and how they work.

IHTH

Comment: @Mr.DemetriusMichael : Note edit, to give you gitDir=/usr/local/git

Answer (score 0):

use command substitution with `$(command)`

```
sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain $(which git)
```

This substitutes the command for its output. You can find all about it in http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

Comment: I'm hoping that this isn't what was wanted, as that would overwrite the `git` binary with `git-credential-osxkeychain`. I imagine the intention was to put them in the same directory (e.g. [GitHub guide](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-mac)). Could do with some clarification from the OP though!

Comment: well, that he could do with double command substitution, namely:  `sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain $(dirname $(which git))` .But hey, whatever the guy wants :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be what [Chirlo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/652378/chirlo) and [shellter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) said.

Why `$echo which wget | sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain` wouldn't work is because piping redirect the stdout from a previous command to the stdin of the next command. In this case, `move` doesn't take input from stdin.

A curious thing is that `which git` returns

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

but you are moving `git-credential-osxkeychain` to

```
/usr/local/git/bin/
```

Those two don't match. Is there a typo or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the pipe syntax, then you should look at `xargs`.